# React: Cannot read property 'method()' of undefined when method is bound

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Hey guys I'm trying to render a table in react which sets a row as selected in the state when it is clicked.

I'm getting an error like this when the row is clicked: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setSelected' of undefined`

There are loads of questions about this and the solution seems to be to add the line `this.setSelected = this.setSelected.bind(this);` to the constructor so that the function is actually accessible.

I already knew to do that and as you can see below, I've done it and it's still giving me the error. I'm completely stumped.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ShowsList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {selected: {showID: null, i: null}};
    this.setSelected = this.setSelected.bind(this);
  }

  setSelected(event, showID, i) {
    this.setState({
      selected: {showID, i}
    });
    console.log(this.state.selected);
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="shows-list">

      <table className="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Location</th>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {this.props.shows.map( function(show, i) {
      return (
        <tr
          key={i}
          onClick={(e) => {this.setSelected(e, show._id, i)}}>
          <td>{i+1}</td>
          <td>{show.eventName}</td>
          <td>{show.location}</td>
          <td>{show.date}</td>
          <td>{show.startTime}</td>
        </tr>);
    })}
  </tbody>
</table>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ShowsList;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript functions declared with function keyword has their own `this` context, so `this` inside `this.props.shows.map( function(show, i)` does not refer to the class. You can use arrow syntax for function declaration which will laxically resolve value of `this`. Change

```
this.props.shows.map(function(show, i)
```

to

```
this.props.shows.map((show, i ) => {
```

Comment: Oh wow, that's an annoying little gotcha for people new to JS. Thanks a lot, I'll keep that in mind when writing my JSX.